# How to display "No results found" on search activity when the query dosen't matches with any result

Tags: android, android-cursor

I have implemented search on my application , it is working . But when the query string dosen't matches with anything it gives me blank screen , instead of that blank screen i want to display "No results found"

Here is my code for searching

```
public Cursor getSearchResults1(String query) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] args=new String[]{query};
    return(getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT _id,section,section_name FROM sections WHERE section_name LIKE '%' || ? || '%'", args));
}
```

Please help me in this

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: Simply check cursor size.

Comment: if cursor count size is 0, set for listview `.setEmptyView` search more on stack. There are plenty of this problems... -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try  this.

```
if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
// Do with the search result 
}else{
// no result
}
```

you can use `cursor.getCount()` but it is more computation expensive as it returns the number of rows for that query, more the number of row more time it will take. Its better to use `cursor.moveToFirst()` if you just want to know whether you got any data for query or not.

Comment: public Cursor getSearchResults1(String query) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  String[] args=new String[]{query};
  Cursor cursor = null;
  if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
   return(getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT _id,section,section_name FROM sections WHERE section_name LIKE '%' || ? || '%'", args));
   }else{
    Toast.makeText(myContext, "zxghgzdfhgzdh", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
  return cursor;  this is what i did but it is giving me null pointer exception

Comment: You don't know Java I think.
you are making `cursor null` just before if condition. This will always throw null pointer exception. get cursor from the query and then go for if and else condition.

`public Cursor getSearchResults1(String query) 
{ 
// TODO Auto-generated method stub 
String[] args=new String[]{query};
Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT _id,section,section_name FROM sections WHERE section_name LIKE '%' || ? || '%'", args);
if(cursor.moveToFirst())
{ 
return cursor;
 }
else
{ 
Toast.makeText(myContext, "zxghgzdfhgzdh", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
}`